# Error in nls model: singular gradient matrix at initial parameter estimates. Cannot figure out appropriate start values

Tags: r, regression, nonlinear-regression, nls

I'm trying to implement equation 3 from this article [research paper](https://www.srs.fs.usda.gov/pubs/gtr/gtr_srs212/gtr_srs212_014.pdf), for ease here's a screenshot of the equation:

[image]

Here's my code for it

```r
taper_model = nls(d ~ (Is*((D^2)*(1 + (((b2 + (b3/D^3))*((1 - 
    (h/H)^b1) - (1 - (1.37/H)^b1)))/(1 - (1 - (1.3/H))^b1))))) + 
    (Ib*(((D^2) - ((((D^2) - (F^2))*(((1 - (1.37/H))^b4) - 
    ((1 - (h/H))^b4)))/(((1 - (1.37/H))^b4) - 
    ((1 - (F/H))^b4))))^0.5)) + 
    (It*((F^2)*((b6*((((h - F)/(H - F)) - 1)^2)) + 
    (Im*(((1 - b6)/(b5^2))*(b5 - ((h - F)/(H - F)))^2))))), 
    data = taper, start=list(b1=1, b2=1, b3=1, b4=1, b5=1, b6=1))
```

and my data looks something like this:

[image]

When I run this, I get the "singular gradient matrix at initial parameter estimates" and I believe it has something to do with the start values.

**For context**, this is a tree taper model. Basically, it's done to be able to predict the diameter of the tree at any given height. So you go up to a tree, point at a particular height on the stem and use the regression coefficients to predict the diameter.

I have tried using random start values but I keep getting the error. I tried to implement the indicator variables as an ifelse statement but it still didn't work.

```r
taper_model_ifelse = nls(d ~ ifelse(h < 1.37, 
       ((D^2)*(1 + (((b2 + (b3/D^3))*((1 - (h/H)^b1) - 
       (1 - (1.37/H)^b1)))/(1 - (1 - (1.3/H))^b1)))), 0)                       
       + ifelse(h > 1.37 & h < F, (((D^2) - 
       ((((D^2) - (F^2))*(((1 - (1.37/H))^b4) - 
       ((1 - (h/H))^b4)))/(((1 - (1.37/H))^b4) - 
       ((1 - (F/H))^b4))))^0.5), 0) + ifelse(h>F, 
       ((F^2)*((b6*((((h - F)/(H - F)) - 1)^2)) + 
       ifelse(0 < (b5-((h-F)/(H-F))), 
       (((1 - b6)/(b5^2))*(b5 - ((h - F)/(H -  F)))^2), 0))), 0), 
       data = taper, start=list(b1=1, b2=1, b3=1, b4=1, b5=1, b6=1))
```

I understand my data is tiny but I am trying to learn how to implement this first before going on to larger datasets. Here's the plot of the data if this would help:

[image]

Do you think the issue is maybe with my data? It's an actual real dataset collected in the field. We fell a tree and cut out the top branches and foliage. The stem was divided into 6 feet segments. At the top of each segment, the diameter was taken. In the dataset:

[image]

I have gone through a lot of previous questions and answers around this issue but none exactly addressed my case, particularly as my model needs to estimate 6 coefficients rather than just two. I would greatly appreciate any help with this.

Comment: Are you sure the equation is correct?  I think the outer brackets are unnecessary. It looks like $I_{s}$ is multiplying everything and since $I_{s}=0$ the `nls()` is not seeing a convergence and thus the error.

Comment: Start by making your code readable (to me it is not!), that makes debugging it easier. Define some functions you can use in the `nls` code, then debug those functions outside the call. There are examples at https://rpubs.com/RobinLovelace/nls-function